# When i add a new column to my dataframe, it shows as NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I needed to add the 'count' value to the dataframe as a new column.

I used the below code:

```
count=HC_Pune.groupby('Customer').size()
HC_Pune.sort_values(by='Customer',inplace=True,ascending=True)
BCP.insert(2,'HC',count,True)
BCP.head(2)
```

This is the output that I get
[image]

Could someone please help me in clearing this problem as to why I am getting `NaN` for the data?

Comment: Provide definition of datasets in code You are working on please.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of your short output,you passed empty values to `count` which are in turn passed to your dataframe. Take a look at your dataset.

Comment: I solved the issue, so basically i was adding a non-dataframe type of data to my BCP Dataframe due to which i was getting NaN.